# Inconsistent print with value from for statement (python)

Tags: python

So I’ve created a very basic program that rolls a dice a given number of times, and then displays who wins the game.
I’ve tried to print the results as they go along with the roll #.

The problem I’m having is the output seems weirdly, an indecipherably (at least to my eyes) inconsistent (ie: sometimes it will show the roll #, sometimes it won’t.

Besides how much cleaner I could make this code, what am I doing that’s producing inconsistent roll # printing?

Code as follows:

```
import random

print("Let's play a little game!")
print("who is the most popular number on a die?")
print("Lets find out!")

def HighRolla():
    ones = 0
    twos = 0
    threes = 0
    fours = 0
    fives = 0
    sixes = 0
    tries = 1

    num_rolls = int(input("How many guesses?"))

    for roll in range(num_rolls):
        ran_num = random.randint(1, 6)
        if ran_num == 1:
            print(f"Roll {tries}: One for the ones")
            ones += 1
        elif ran_num == 2:
            print("Roll {tries}: Two Two look at my shoe")
            twos += 1
        elif ran_num == 3:
            print("Roll {tries}: THREE!! I'm free'")
            threes += 1
        elif ran_num == 4:
            print("Roll {tries}: F0ar equals m0ar")
            fours += 1
        elif ran_num == 5:
            print("Roll {tries}: Five five don't step in a bee hive'")
            fives += 1
        elif ran_num == 6:
            print("Roll {tries}: Super Sixes - Yeharrrr!")
            sixes += 1
    rolls += 1
    tries += 1  
    print(f"Final scores are: \n1: {ones}\n2: {twos}\n3: {threes}\n4: {fours}\n5: {fives}\n6: {sixes}")
    
    
HighRolla()’’’
```

Comment: The print statements for 2 through 6 are missing the `f` at the beginning of the string, so it prints the actual text `{tries}` instead of the value.

Comment: Your edit put the `rolls` and `tries` outside the for-loop. Please post your actual code as it's currently written and don't change it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: You forgot the `f` at the start of the strings in the print statements for 2 through 6. Therefore, it prints the actual text {tries} instead of the value.

In addition, I'd recommend:

- Using a dictionary instead of all of those ifs.
- Note that you didn't initialize `rolls` before using it, and you also set `tries` to 1 instead of 0. There is also no use for `rolls`.
- Using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for counting the results, instead of initializing a separate variable for each number. `defaultdict` returns a new dictionary-like object, where the first argument provides the initial value for the default_factory.
- Method names in python should also be lowercase and seperated by `_`.

Implementing those steps would make your code much shorter and more pythonic.

Putting it all together:

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

print("Let's play a little game!")
print("who is the most popular number on a die?")
print("Lets find out!")

def high_rolla():
    num_rolls = int(input("How many guesses?"))
    random_results = defaultdict(int)
    tries = 0
    random_to_print = {1: "One for the ones",
                       2: "Two Two look at my shoe",
                       3: "THREE!! I'm free'",
                       4: "F0ar equals m0ar",
                       5: "Five five don't step in a bee hive'",
                       6: "Super Sixes - Yeharrrr!"}
    for roll in range(num_rolls):
        ran_num = random.randint(1, 6)
        tries += 1
        print(f"Roll {tries}: " + random_to_print[ran_num])
        random_results[ran_num] += 1  
    print("Final scores are: ")
    for key, value in random_results.items():
        print(str(key) + " : " + str(value))
    
    
high_rolla()
```

Output:

```
Let's play a little game!
who is the most popular number on a die?
Lets find out!
How many guesses?3
Roll 1: Two Two look at my shoe
Roll 2: Two Two look at my shoe
Roll 3: One for the ones
Final scores are: 
2 : 2
1 : 1
```

Comment: F-strings are string literals and are evaluated when declared, so won't all of those always print with `tries = 0`?

Comment: @CrazyChucky Your'e right, I wasn't aware of that. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't use f-Strings correctly. If you want your variables to be replaced inside curly brackets you need to put an "f" in front of your string.

You could also use a dictionary or an array to make your code clearer and more readable, like so:

```
import random

print("Let's play a little game!")
print("who is the most popular number on a die?")
print("Lets find out!")

def HighRolla():
    roll_counts = [0] * 6 # Creates an array of 6 zeroes
    roll_messages = [
        "One for the ones",
        "Two Two look at my shoe",
        "THREE!! I'm free'",
        "F0ar equals m0ar",
        "Five five don't step in a bee hive'",
        "Super Sixes - Yeharrrr!"
    ]

    num_rolls = int(input("How many guesses?"))

    for roll in range(num_rolls):
        ran_num = random.randint(1, 6)
        roll_counts[ran_num-1] += 1
        print(f"Roll {roll}: {roll_messages[ran_num-1]}")
    
    print(f"Final scores are:")
    print("\n".join([f"{idx+1}: {roll_count}" for idx, roll_count in enumerate(roll_counts)]))
    
HighRolla()
```

Comment: Oh wow how embarrassing that I didn’t pick that up. Thanks for reading over this, and more importantly showing me other ways to achieve my result with dictionaries. Thanks guys and girls

Comment: No worries, please accept an answer if your problem is solved.